# How to fix a CORS error in NUXT3 with router navigation , back button, or anything that includes caching?

Tags: express, caching, cors, browser-cache, nuxtjs3

Ok, so I have a **Nuxt3** app and **Express API**. API has a list of **allowed origins** and that's all fine, but I get **CORS** error with NUXTLINK navigation to a page that has a **useFetch()**.
I believe it has **something to do with caching**. Any ideas?